# how to control font and text bold in shinyRGL 3D plot

Tags: r, 3d, shiny, rgl

I set up a shiny app with the 'shinyRGL' package to produce a rotatable cube like the one in the post [here](http://trestletech.com/2013/10/interactive-3d-in-shiny-shinyrgl/).

what I get, with 5 points is this: 
[image]

I want to reduce the size of the labels, so I use `cex=0.4` for instance, but then it becomes unreadable (all blurry and still bold...I don't know why?). Is there a way to fix this? Same problem occurs for the axis names and ticks.
[image]

I post my code (if needed I can post the whole server.R but it's pretty similar to the code in the link...)

```
x=rnorm(5); y=rnorm(5); z=rnorm(5)
plot3d(x, y, z, size=6,
       xlab="my axis X", ylab="my axis Y", zlab="my axis Z")
text3d(x,y,z, text=c("my text for first point", "my text for second point", "my text for thrid point",
                     "my text for fourth point", "my text for fifth point"), cex=0.4)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the font? There's plenty of info in `?text3d`

Comment: ok, i just tried it but it doesn't work: all the different fonts produce the same exact aspect. the problem seems specific to the shinyRGL package

Comment: The author of this package says(in github) that shinyRGL project is to be updated according to the new RGL package and he cant do that at this point of time. May be that's the reason for these glitches.

Comment: all right then, thanks for the comment, if so i'll wait !

Answer (score 0):

Set cex = 1.5, a bigger value. It works for me when I want to enlarge the axis tick labels.